# C - check if string is a substring of another string

Tags: c, string, substring

I need to write a program that takes two strings as arguments and check if the second one is a substring of the first one. I need to do it without using any special library functions. I created this implementation, but I think it's always returning true as long as there is one letter that's the same in both strings. Can you help me out here. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int my_strstr( char const *s, char const *sub ) {
    char const *ret = sub;

    int r = 0;
    while ( ret = strchr( ret, *sub ) ) {
        if ( strcmp( ++ret, sub+1 ) == 0 ){
            r = 1;
        }
        else{
            r = 0;
        }        
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf ("Usage: check <string one> <string two>\n");
    }
    int result = my_strstr(argv[1], argv[2]);

    if(result == 1){
        printf("%s is a substring of %s\n", argv[2], argv[1]);
    } else{
        printf("%s is not a substring of %s\n", argv[2], argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you "need to do it without using any special library functions" then you shouldn't use strchr and strcmp. actually strcmp is where your problem is anyway.

Comment: @stmax: Those are just _ordinary_ library functions. There's nothing special in them :)

Comment: @Daniel: if `strchr()` and `strcmp()` are ordinary, so is `strstr()`...

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Sure. I was pointing out, indeed, that in fact there are no "special" library functions - just library functions, period.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to writing `strstr` is fundamentally flawed. Let's look at what you wrote:

```
char const *ret = sub;

int r = 0;
while ( ret = strchr( ret, *sub ) ) {
    if ( strcmp( ++ret, sub+1 ) == 0 ){
        r = 1;
    }
    else{
        r = 0;
    }        
}
return r;
```

First of all, since you initialize `ret` to point to `sub`, you are comparing `sub` against itself, and never looking at `s`. But let's assume that you meant for `ret` to be initialized to `s`...

`ret = strchr( ret, *sub )` finds the position of the next character of `sub` within `ret`, and then advances `ret` so that it starts on that character.

Then, you execute `strcmp( ++ret, sub+1 )` which determines if the string beginning from the next character of `ret` is equal to the string beginning from the next character of `sub`, and then advances `ret` to start with the next character (regardless of whether the test was true or false).

Clearly, this logic isn't doing what you want. What it will actually do is determine if the substring is either equal to the string `s` or is found at the *end* of the string `s` and includes no repeated letters.

Here's a general outline of the algorithm you want:

1. Find the position of the first character of `sub` in `s`. If not found, return false.
2. Update `s` so that it starts at this position
3. Assuming the length of `sub` is `n`, test if the first `n` characters of `s` match `sub` (being careful not to run past the end of `s`). If so, return true. Otherwise, advance `s` by one character and loop.

Note that you should never be searching for any character in `sub` other than the first. The idea is to use the first character of `sub` to find *potential* starting positions for `sub` in `s`, and then check if the substring `sub` actually exists there. If it isn't there, you want discard the entirety of `s` up to that point, and then start over by trying to find the next potential starting position.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you shouldn't be modifying `ret` in `my_strstr`. And `strcmp` does not compare substrings, it compares strings. You probably want to use `strncmp`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are searching for char *sub in char * sub:

```
int my_strstr( char const *s, char const *sub ) {
char const *ret = sub;
```

shouldn't you be setting ret to s?

Also strcmp compares strings, not sub strings so strcmp("abcde", "abc") returns false.  You probably want strncmp which also takes an integer specifying the length.

Answer (score 0):

When

```
ret = strchr( ret, *sub )
```

is first encountered, `ret == sub`. So, `strchr(ret, *sub)` is searching **the first occurrence of the first char of `ret` in `ret`**. Which will return `ret`.

So, `ret` remains unchanged.

Next,

```
strcmp( ++ret, sub+1 ) == 0
```

`ret` is still equal to `sub`, so the above statement is **true**.

And you get `1` as return.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to break this task down a bit differently.  There are two key parts to this task: 1) finding the starting point of potential sub-string matches and 2) testing whether that starting point is indeed a matching sub-string.  Therefore, implement this as two functions.

First , create a function that determines if two strings are exactly alike.  This should be relatively easy to code, just compare first letter with first letter, second with second, etc.  If you find two that don't match, return false.  If you make it to the end of one of the strings, return true.  If you are allowed to use `strncmp`, then this would simply be `(strncmp(a, b, strlen(b)) == 0)` (assuming `b` is always the shorter string).

Second, create a function that loops through a string, looking for a certain letter.  Whenever it finds that letter, it calls a function and passes a pointer to that letter in the string.  In other words, if you called `my_function("This is a sample string", 's')`, then the function should walk through the string, find all four instances of the letter 's' and call a function using a pointer to that letter in the string.  In this case, the function you will call is the function described in the previous paragraph.

Using this breakdown, you will return "true" as soon as any of the calls to the sub-function return "true", or you will return "false" if you make it to the end of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

```
char const *ret = sub;

int r = 0;
while ( ret = strchr( ret, *sub ) ) {
```

ret is storing the address of sub array and in
 while statement `strchr(ret,*sub)`
comparing value in `sub` with address stored in `ret`
whether this will work or not (this comparison is right or not)
answer anyone please...